# Joining DataFrames Horizontally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which consists of data that is indexed by the date. So the index has dates ranging from 6-1 to 6-18.

What I need to do is perform a "pivot" or a horizontal merge, based on the date.

So for example, lets say today is 6-18. I need to go through this dataframe, and find the dates which are 6-18, basically pivot/join them horizontally to the same dataframe.

Expected output (1 signifies there is data there, 0 signifies null/NaN):
Before the join, df:

```
date | x | y | z 
6-15 | 1 | 1 | 1
6-15 | 2 | 2 | 2 
6-18 | 3 | 3 | 3
6-18 | 3 | 3 | 3
```

Joining the df on 6-18:

```
date | x | y | z | x (6-18) | y (6-18) | z (6-18)
6-15 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0        | 0        | 0
6-15 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0        | 0        | 0
6-18 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1        | 1        | 1
6-18 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1        | 1        | 1
```

When I use append, or join or merge, what I get is this:

```
date | x | y | z | x (6-18) | y (6-18) | z (6-18)
6-15 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0        | 0        | 0
6-15 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0        | 0        | 0
6-18 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0        | 0        | 0
6-18 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0        | 0        | 0
6-18 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1        | 1        | 1
6-18 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1        | 1        | 1
```

What I've done is extract the date that I want, to a new dataframe using loc.

```
df_daily = df_metrics.loc[str(_date_map['daily']['start'].date())]
df_daily.columns = [str(cols) + " (Daily)" if cols in metric_names else cols for cols in df_daily.columns]
```

And then joining it to the master df:

```
df = df.join(df_daily, lsuffix=' (Daily)', rsuffix=' (Monthly)').reset_index()
```

When I try joining or merging, the dataset gets so big because I'm assuming it's doing a comparison of each row. So when 1 date of 1 row doesn't match, it will create a new row with NaN.

My dataset turns from a 30k row piece, to 2.8 million.

Comment: You've shown your expected output (along with the incorrect ones), but what is your input?

Comment: It would be good if you can share a bit more details including your actual input and desired output data sets. Thereafter, can try to help you to solve your problem.